# Spotify API: How to crossfade songs

Tags: spotify

I'm using the Spotify API 11.1.60 for iOS and created successfully an app that can download / play songs from Spotify, download and show the covers, execute searches.  But I can't find a way to crossfade songs. I only can play one song a time.

Does anybody know how to crossfade songs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not implement crossfade but I think the only solution is to bufferize your current song to be able to crossfade.

You have to update your music_delivery callback and your code used to play the sound. The solution depend on the sound engine your using (OpenAL, CoreAudio, ...)

Comment: This is the correct way to approach this — libSpotify makes no assumptions about what you do with the audio. If you want to crossfade, you need to do it yourself.